# Css variable not applied on pages

Tags: css, asp.net

I added Bootstrap last version, folder CSS and Js, and attached with asp.net master page everything working correctly with the master page (Theme side), additionally added another Style sheet to apply external changes on others pages. I create a login page to add some responsibility on it, but a wrote variables in style sheet not applied on the login page.  So how to solve that...Thanks
/////////
/*Start-Login Page Style*/

```
  .div-ground{
  background-image:url('../images/ch2.jpg');
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-size:cover;

}
.log-style {
    opacity:0.5;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);  
}
  /*End-Login Page Style*/
```

Login page code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="login.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.login" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

  <div id="div-ground">
    <div id="log-style">
      <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" CreateUserText="SignUp for new account" CreateUserUrl="~/signup.aspx" DestinationPageUrl="~/admin/Default.aspx" OnLoggedIn="Login1_LoggedIn" CssClass="form-group">
      </asp:Login>
    </div>
  </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Master Page code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/>
  <meta name="description" content=""/>
  <meta name="author" content=""/>
  <link href="../admin/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="~/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="~/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <link href="~/theme/maintheme.css" rel="stylesheet" runat="server" />
  <title></title>
```

Comment: For CSS rules to target `id='foo'` you need to use `#` as a prefix, not a period. For example: `#div-ground { ... }`

Comment: Thanks DavidG..a problem solved